# How to fix error "Cannot dispatch middleware Application\Middleware\IndexMiddleware"?

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, service-locator, zend-framework3

I've set up a Zend Application as normal, except in my case the difference is that I set it up *over* an existing legacy web application.

I still want to call my existing legacy application over the ZF3 app.  It was suggested I can do so using Middleware.  I went over https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/middleware/ and set up my routing as described there.

However, when I run the application, I am greeted by this:

```
Cannot dispatch middleware Application\Middleware\IndexMiddleware

#0 zend-mvc\src\MiddlewareListener.php(146): 
Zend\Mvc\Exception\InvalidMiddlewareException::fromMiddlewareName('Application\\Mid...')
```

Here is where the exception happens:
https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/release-3.1.0/src/MiddlewareListener.php#L146

Just to note:

```
$middlewareToBePiped; //'Application\Middleware\IndexMiddleware'
is_string($middlewareToBePiped); // true
$serviceLocator->has($middlewareToBePiped);//false
$middlewareToBePiped instanceof MiddlewareInterface; //false
is_callable($middlewareToBePiped);//false
```

My class is:

```
namespace Application\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\MiddlewareInterface;
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\DelegateInterface;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class IndexMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{

    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {}

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, DelegateInterface $delegate)
    {}
}
```

I am thinking that my issue is that my `IndexMiddleware` class is not being found in ServiceLocator... (line 142 of linked API).  How do I get it in there?

Answer (score 0):

I put this into my application.config.php file:

```
'service_manager' => [
    'invokables' => array(
        'middleware' => IndexMiddleware::class
    )
]
```

onto the next error it is.. (Last middleware executed did not return a response.)
but looks like it has executed)